# send this keyword along with page.call in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am having

```
      <%= link_to_function "Show additional details",:id => 'user_', :class => 'underline' do |page|
     page.call 'toggle_detail','additional'
    end -%>
```

how to send this keyword along with the page.call here. pls give suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try page.call `'foobar',page.literal('this')`